# Merge 3 columns into 1 with multiple nested select

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gis, apache-superset, deck.gl

I have some data that i need to display on a path layer on deckgl inside super set, the format of the data has to be very specific or else it throws errors, the format is as such
[[],[],[]] anything else will throw errors. My data is in long and lat format which i was able to transform in to proper form, except that some lines are multistring which has this format [[[],[]],[[]]]. i am able to get it into proper format separately in 3 different columns, how do i merge these 3 into 1? tried union distinct by basing my self on this example, with an error "Expected keyword JOIN but got "," at [3:98]" how do i solve this?

```
    SELECT * FROM Employee_Asia UNION DISTINCT SELECT * from 
    Employee_Europe
    ****
    select * from(
    (select replace(substring(geo,1),"[[[", "[[") as ngeo union 
    DISTINCT  
    (select replace 
    (substring(geo,1),"]]]", "]]")) union DISTINCT select replace 
    (substring(geo,1),"]],[[" ,"], [")), from(
    ****


select replace(substring(geo,1),"[[[", "[[") as ngeo, (select replace 
(substring(geo,1),"]]]", "]]"))as xgeo,  (select replace (substring(geo,1),"]],[[" ,"], 
["))as zgeo,from(
select geo from ( 
SELECT 
routeID ,  json_extract(st_asgeojson(st_makeline( array_agg(st_geogpoint(locs.lon, 
locs.lat) order by locs.date))),'$.coordinates') as geo,
FROM 
howardcounty.routebatches
cross join UNNEST(locations) as locs
where  locs.date between {{start_date}} and {{end_date}} 
group by routeID 
order by routeID
limit 7
)where length(geo)-length(replace(geo,"]","")) > 1+4 
)
```

here is a the result from the query without union, am also limited to select only.

```
[[-76.832895,39.20946],[-76.8328744528093,39.2094841310634], 
[-76.8327537674778,39.2096258661087],[-76.8327516666667,39.2096283333333], 
[-76.8326516666667,39.20973],[-76.8326416666667,39.2098316666667], 
[-76.8327033333333,39.2099316666667],[-76.83284,39.2099916666667], 
[-76.8329033333333,39.210025],[-76.8331,39.2101616666667],  
[-76.8332383333333,39.2102366666667],[-76.8333933333333,39.2103233333333], 
[-76.8335416666667,39.2103883333333],[-76.8336783333333,39.21044], 
[-76.8338,39.2104816666667],[-76.83389,39.2105533333333], 
[-76.83389633091,39.2105767090203],[-76.8339113352774,39.2106321097435], 
[-76.8339116666667,39.2106333333333],[-76.8338887881129,39.2106764906686], 
[-76.8338383333333,39.2107716666667],[-76.8337783333333,39.2108866666667], 
[-76.8337710512136,39.2110192012812],[-76.83377,39.2110383333333], 
[-76.8338232468397,39.2111109427531],[-76.83388,39.2111883333333], 
[-76.8340466666667,39.2111883333333],[-76.834145,39.211135], 
[-76.8341866666667,39.2110433333333],[-76.8342116666667,39.2110016666667], 
[-76.83428,39.2108766666667],[-76.8343283333333,39.210795],[-76.83439,39.2107266666667], 
[-76.8344492363899,39.2106641394387],[-76.83451,39.2106],[-76.834715,39.21045], 
[-76.8349033333333,39.2103033333333],[-76.83497,39.21014],[-76.8349733333333,39.21006], 
[-76.834985,39.21022],[-76.834865,39.2104133333333],[-76.83476,39.21059], 
[-76.8347916666667,39.21075],[-76.8350466666667,39.2108316666667], 
[-76.8352283333333,39.2107116666667],[-76.83532,39.2105266666667], 
[-76.8354483333333,39.2103633333333],[-76.83555,39.21017], 
[-76.8356666666667,39.2100466666667],[-76.8358216666667,39.21004], 
[-76.8358733333333,39.2101316666667],[-76.8358316666667,39.2102883333333], 
[-76.8359,39.210425],[-76.8358689842204,39.2104852071477],[-76.8358433333333,39.210535], 
[-76.8356983333333,39.210565],[-76.8357383333333,39.210475], 
[-76.8358689842204,39.2104852071477],[-76.8359516666667,39.2104916666667], 
[-76.8360516666667,39.210455],[-76.8361533333333,39.2102916666667], 
[-76.836285,39.210175],[-76.8364766666667,39.21023],[-76.8366683333333,39.21028], 
[-76.8368166666667,39.210305],[-76.836955,39.2103233333333], 
[-76.83699,39.2103183333333],[-76.8373016666667,39.2103166666667], 
[-76.8374566666667,39.2103016666667],[-76.8376066666667,39.21029], 
[-76.8377616666667,39.2103016666667],[-76.83795,39.210335], 
[-76.8381333333333,39.2104033333333],[-76.83831,39.2105133333333], 
[-76.8384333333333,39.2106416666667],[-76.8385183333333,39.210785], 
[-76.8385616666667,39.210935],[-76.838585,39.2110366666667], 
[-76.8386083333334,39.2111266666667],[-76.83865,39.211245], 
[-76.8387166666667,39.211505],[-76.838855,39.2116916666667], 
[-76.839035,39.2118216666667],[-76.8392,39.2119766666667],[-76.8393516666667,39.212125], 
[-76.83948,39.21218],[-76.8395733333333,39.2121633333333], 
[-76.8398377180994,39.212155736099],[-76.839863333316,39.2121550000005], 
[-76.8398633333333,39.212155],[-76.839866248213,39.2121550000002], 
[-76.8398683333333,39.212155],[-76.839885,39.212155]], 
[[-76.839863333316,39.2121550000005],[-76.83984,39.212155], 
[-76.8398377180994,39.212155736099],[-76.839685,39.212205], 
[-76.8395033333333,39.212245],[-76.83924,39.2121616666667], 
[-76.8390316666667,39.2119483333333],[-76.8388216666667,39.2117766666667], 
[-76.8387066666667,39.21161],[-76.838545,39.21148],[-76.8383866666667,39.211435], 
[-76.8381966666667,39.2114216666667],[-76.8380266666667,39.21142], 
[-76.8378533333333,39.2114133333333],[-76.8376933333333,39.2114116666667], 
[-76.837545,39.2113983333333],[-76.837365,39.2114166666667], 
[-76.837145,39.2113883333333],[-76.83696,39.2113683333333],[-76.8368116666667,39.21135], 
[-76.8366616666667,39.211345],[-76.8365166666667,39.21134], 
[-76.836395,39.2113383333333],[-76.83635,39.21134],[-76.8361416666667,39.21133], 
[-76.8359466666667,39.2112916666667],[-76.8358183333333,39.2112233333333], 
[-76.8357733333333,39.2111683333333],[-76.8357366666667,39.211055], 
[-76.8356816666667,39.2109716666667],[-76.83552,39.211005], 
[-76.8353483333333,39.2109983333333],[-76.8351966666667,39.2109416666667], 
[-76.835055,39.210885],[-76.8349033333333,39.21081],[-76.83475,39.2107766666667], 
[-76.834625,39.2107333333333],[-76.83449,39.2106866666667], 
[-76.8344492363899,39.2106641394387],[-76.8343633333333,39.2106166666667], 
[-76.834205,39.21054],[-76.8340283333333,39.2105483333333], 
[-76.833938122743,39.2106129286176],[-76.8339113352774,39.2106321097435], 
[-76.8338933333333,39.210645],[-76.8338216666667,39.2107666666667], 
[-76.83377,39.2108516666667],[-76.8337333333333,39.2109116666667], 
[-76.8337122666612,39.2109696000596],[-76.8336933333333,39.2110216666667], 
[-76.8337276727651,39.2110803760451],[-76.833745,39.21111], 
[-76.8338232468397,39.2111109427531],[-76.8338833333333,39.2111116666667], 
[-76.83392,39.211055],[-76.8339716666667,39.2109833333333], 
[-76.8340783333333,39.2108283333333],[-76.8340766666667,39.210725], 
[-76.8339833333333,39.2106566666667],[-76.8339611067922,39.2106613270793], 
[-76.8338887881129,39.2106764906686],[-76.83388,39.2106783333333], 
[-76.8338083333333,39.2108016666667],[-76.83373,39.2109366666667], 
[-76.8337122666612,39.2109696000596],[-76.83366,39.2110666666667], 
[-76.8335933333333,39.21119],[-76.8335266666667,39.211375],[-76.83353,39.2116183333333], 
[-76.833635,39.2118683333333],[-76.8338283333333,39.212085], 
[-76.8340583333333,39.2123116666667],[-76.8342483333333,39.21253],[-76.834345,39.21274], 
[-76.8344233333333,39.212935],[-76.8343933333333,39.21316], 
[-76.8345383333333,39.2133166666667],[-76.8347266666667,39.213195], 
[-76.8345933333333,39.2129983333333],[-76.834455,39.2127816666667], 
[-76.8343833333333,39.212615],[-76.834365,39.2125766666667], 
[-76.83429,39.2124883333333],[-76.83412,39.21229],[-76.8339066666667,39.2120766666667], 
[-76.8337066666667,39.21187],[-76.8336,39.2116516666667], 
[-76.8335816666667,39.2114666666667],[-76.8336083333333,39.211325], 
[-76.8336516666667,39.2112016666667],[-76.8337066666667,39.21111], 
[-76.8337276727651,39.2110803760451],[-76.8337710512136,39.2110192012812], 
[-76.8337716666667,39.2110183333333],[-76.8338516666667,39.2109], 
[-76.83392,39.2108133333333],[-76.83396,39.2107166666667], 
[-76.8339611067922,39.2106613270793],[-76.8339616666667,39.2106333333333], 
[-76.833938122743,39.2106129286176],[-76.83389633091,39.2105767090203], 
[-76.8338866666667,39.2105683333333],[-76.833715,39.2105016666667], 
[-76.833595,39.2104533333333],[-76.83358,39.21045],[-76.833405,39.2103716666667], 
[-76.83337,39.210365],[-76.8332116666667,39.2103166666667],[-76.8330966666667,39.21027],
[-76.83299,39.2102233333333],[-76.83286,39.2101766666667], 
[-76.8327283333333,39.2101333333333],[-76.8325683333333,39.2100616666667], 
[-76.832535,39.2100016666667],[-76.8325183333333,39.2098966666667], 
[-76.8325066666667,39.2097333333333],[-76.8324919958592,39.209720248584], 
[-76.8323833333333,39.2096233333333],[-76.8321633333333,39.2095333333333], 
[-76.8320825997553,39.20948763515],[-76.8319866666667,39.2094333333333], 
[-76.8319816666667,39.2092766666667],[-76.83207,39.2091466666667],[-76.832225,39.20905], 
[-76.8323483333333,39.2091416666667],[-76.8322416666667,39.2093283333333], 
[-76.8321066666667,39.209475],[-76.8320825997553,39.20948763515], 
[-76.8319733333333,39.209545],[-76.831862668414,39.20954057341], 
[-76.8318483333334,39.20954],[-76.8318415539569,39.2095171966764], 
[-76.8318116666667,39.2094166666667],[-76.8318683333333,39.2093033333333], 
[-76.8319233333333,39.209195],[-76.8318483333334,39.2091033333333], 
[-76.8317466666667,39.2090916666667],[-76.8317216666667,39.209135], 
[-76.8317866666667,39.2093583333333],[-76.83182,39.2094933333333], 
[-76.8318415539569,39.2095171966764],[-76.831862668414,39.20954057341], 
[-76.8319133333333,39.2095966666667],[-76.8318683333333,39.2097], 
[-76.8318416666667,39.2097383333333],[-76.8318116666667,39.2098966666667], 
[-76.8319366666667,39.2099516666667],[-76.832085,39.21],[-76.83213,39.21008], 
[-76.8322416666667,39.2101083333333],[-76.832365,39.2100483333333], 
[-76.8324283333333,39.20996],[-76.832475,39.209885],[-76.83249,39.20984], 
[-76.8324919958592,39.209720248584],[-76.8324924676826,39.2096919391536], 
[-76.8324933333333,39.20964],[-76.8325983333333,39.2094983333333], 
[-76.8326833333333,39.2093466666667],[-76.83268,39.2091916666667], 
[-76.8324833333333,39.2091266666667],[-76.8323283333333,39.2092133333333], 
[-76.83233,39.209355],[-76.8323516666667,39.209475], 
[-76.8323933333333,39.2096216666667],[-76.8324924676826,39.2096919391536], 
[-76.832525,39.209715],[-76.8326783333333,39.2096816666667], 
[-76.8327537674778,39.2096258661087],[-76.8328,39.2095916666667], 
[-76.8328766666667,39.2095216666667],[-76.8329,39.20949], 
[-76.8328744528093,39.2094841310634],[-76.8327766666667,39.2094616666667], 
[-76.8327466666667,39.2095066666667],[-76.832685,39.209635], 
[-76.83268,39.2096466666667]]]  [[[-76.832895,39.20946], 
[-76.8328744528093,39.2094841310634],[-76.8327537674778,39.2096258661087], 
[-76.8327516666667,39.2096283333333],[-76.8326516666667,39.20973], 
[-76.8326416666667,39.2098316666667],[-76.8327033333333,39.2099316666667], 
[-76.83284,39.2099916666667],[-76.8329033333333,39.210025],[-76.8331,39.2101616666667], 
[-76.8332383333333,39.2102366666667],[-76.8333933333333,39.2103233333333], 
[-76.8335416666667,39.2103883333333],[-76.8336783333333,39.21044], 
[-76.8338,39.2104816666667],[-76.83389,39.2105533333333], 
[-76.83389633091,39.2105767090203],[-76.8339113352774,39.2106321097435], 
[-76.8339116666667,39.2106333333333],[-76.8338887881129,39.2106764906686], 
[-76.8338383333333,39.2107716666667],[-76.8337783333333,39.2108866666667], 
[-76.8337710512136,39.2110192012812],[-76.83377,39.2110383333333], 
[-76.8338232468397,39.2111109427531],[-76.83388,39.2111883333333], 
[-76.8340466666667,39.2111883333333],[-76.834145,39.211135], 
[-76.8341866666667,39.2110433333333],[-76.8342116666667,39.2110016666667], 
[-76.83428,39.2108766666667],[-76.8343283333333,39.210795],[-76.83439,39.2107266666667], 
[-76.8344492363899,39.2106641394387],[-76.83451,39.2106],[-76.834715,39.21045], 
[-76.8349033333333,39.2103033333333],[-76.83497,39.21014],[-76.8349733333333,39.21006], 
[-76.834985,39.21022],[-76.834865,39.2104133333333],[-76.83476,39.21059], 
[-76.8347916666667,39.21075],[-76.8350466666667,39.2108316666667], 
[-76.8352283333333,39.2107116666667],[-76.83532,39.2105266666667], 
[-76.8354483333333,39.2103633333333],[-76.83555,39.21017], 
[-76.8356666666667,39.2100466666667],[-76.8358216666667,39.21004], 
[-76.8358733333333,39.2101316666667],[-76.8358316666667,39.2102883333333], 
[-76.8359,39.210425],[-76.8358689842204,39.2104852071477],[-76.8358433333333,39.210535], 
[-76.8356983333333,39.210565],[-76.8357383333333,39.210475], 
[-76.8358689842204,39.2104852071477],[-76.8359516666667,39.2104916666667], 
[-76.8360516666667,39.210455],[-76.8361533333333,39.2102916666667], 
[-76.836285,39.210175],[-76.8364766666667,39.21023],[-76.8366683333333,39.21028], 
[-76.8368166666667,39.210305],[-76.836955,39.2103233333333], 
[-76.83699,39.2103183333333],[-76.8373016666667,39.2103166666667], 
[-76.8374566666667,39.2103016666667],[-76.8376066666667,39.21029], 
[-76.8377616666667,39.2103016666667],[-76.83795,39.210335], 
[-76.8381333333333,39.2104033333333],[-76.83831,39.2105133333333], 
[-76.8384333333333,39.2106416666667],[-76.8385183333333,39.210785], 
[-76.8385616666667,39.210935],[-76.838585,39.2110366666667], 
[-76.8386083333334,39.2111266666667],[-76.83865,39.211245], 
[-76.8387166666667,39.211505],[-76.838855,39.2116916666667], 
[-76.839035,39.2118216666667],[-76.8392,39.2119766666667],[-76.8393516666667,39.212125], 
[-76.83948,39.21218],[-76.8395733333333,39.2121633333333], 
[-76.8398377180994,39.212155736099],[-76.839863333316,39.2121550000005], 
[-76.8398633333333,39.212155],[-76.839866248213,39.2121550000002], 
[-76.8398683333333,39.212155],[-76.839885,39.212155]], 
[[-76.839863333316,39.2121550000005],[-76.83984,39.212155], 
[-76.8398377180994,39.212155736099],[-76.839685,39.212205], 
[-76.8395033333333,39.212245],[-76.83924,39.2121616666667], 
[-76.8390316666667,39.2119483333333],[-76.8388216666667,39.2117766666667], 
[-76.8387066666667,39.21161],[-76.838545,39.21148],[-76.8383866666667,39.211435], 
[-76.8381966666667,39.2114216666667],[-76.8380266666667,39.21142], 
[-76.8378533333333,39.2114133333333],[-76.8376933333333,39.2114116666667], 
[-76.837545,39.2113983333333],[-76.837365,39.2114166666667], 
[-76.837145,39.2113883333333],[-76.83696,39.2113683333333],[-76.8368116666667,39.21135], 
[-76.8366616666667,39.211345],[-76.8365166666667,39.21134], 
[-76.836395,39.2113383333333],[-76.83635,39.21134],[-76.8361416666667,39.21133], 
[-76.8359466666667,39.2112916666667],[-76.8358183333333,39.2112233333333], 
[-76.8357733333333,39.2111683333333],[-76.8357366666667,39.211055], 
[-76.8356816666667,39.2109716666667],[-76.83552,39.211005], 
[-76.8353483333333,39.2109983333333],[-76.8351966666667,39.2109416666667], 
[-76.835055,39.210885],[-76.8349033333333,39.21081],[-76.83475,39.2107766666667], 
[-76.834625,39.2107333333333],[-76.83449,39.2106866666667], 
[-76.8344492363899,39.2106641394387],[-76.8343633333333,39.2106166666667], 
[-76.834205,39.21054],[-76.8340283333333,39.2105483333333], 
[-76.833938122743,39.2106129286176],[-76.8339113352774,39.2106321097435], 
[-76.8338933333333,39.210645],[-76.8338216666667,39.2107666666667], 
[-76.83377,39.2108516666667],[-76.8337333333333,39.2109116666667], 
[-76.8337122666612,39.2109696000596],[-76.8336933333333,39.2110216666667], 
[-76.8337276727651,39.2110803760451],[-76.833745,39.21111], 
[-76.8338232468397,39.2111109427531],[-76.8338833333333,39.2111116666667], 
[-76.83392,39.211055],[-76.8339716666667,39.2109833333333], 
[-76.8340783333333,39.2108283333333],[-76.8340766666667,39.210725], 
[-76.8339833333333,39.2106566666667],[-76.8339611067922,39.2106613270793], 
[-76.8338887881129,39.2106764906686],[-76.83388,39.2106783333333], 
[-76.8338083333333,39.2108016666667],[-76.83373,39.2109366666667], 
[-76.8337122666612,39.2109696000596],[-76.83366,39.2110666666667], 
[-76.8335933333333,39.21119],[-76.8335266666667,39.211375],[-76.83353,39.2116183333333], 
[-76.833635,39.2118683333333],[-76.8338283333333,39.212085], 
[-76.8340583333333,39.2123116666667],[-76.8342483333333,39.21253],[-76.834345,39.21274], 
[-76.8344233333333,39.212935],[-76.8343933333333,39.21316], 
[-76.8345383333333,39.2133166666667],[-76.8347266666667,39.213195], 
[-76.8345933333333,39.2129983333333],[-76.834455,39.2127816666667], 
[-76.8343833333333,39.212615],[-76.834365,39.2125766666667], 
[-76.83429,39.2124883333333],[-76.83412,39.21229],[-76.8339066666667,39.2120766666667], 
[-76.8337066666667,39.21187],[-76.8336,39.2116516666667], 
[-76.8335816666667,39.2114666666667],[-76.8336083333333,39.211325], 
[-76.8336516666667,39.2112016666667],[-76.8337066666667,39.21111], 
[-76.8337276727651,39.2110803760451],[-76.8337710512136,39.2110192012812], 
[-76.8337716666667,39.2110183333333],[-76.8338516666667,39.2109], 
[-76.83392,39.2108133333333],[-76.83396,39.2107166666667], 
[-76.8339611067922,39.2106613270793],[-76.8339616666667,39.2106333333333], 
[-76.833938122743,39.2106129286176],[-76.83389633091,39.2105767090203], 
[-76.8338866666667,39.2105683333333],[-76.833715,39.2105016666667], 
[-76.833595,39.2104533333333],[-76.83358,39.21045],[-76.833405,39.2103716666667], 
[-76.83337,39.210365],[-76.8332116666667,39.2103166666667],[-76.8330966666667,39.21027], 
[-76.83299,39.2102233333333],[-76.83286,39.2101766666667], 
[-76.8327283333333,39.2101333333333],[-76.8325683333333,39.2100616666667], 
[-76.832535,39.2100016666667],[-76.8325183333333,39.2098966666667], 
[-76.8325066666667,39.2097333333333],[-76.8324919958592,39.209720248584], 
[-76.8323833333333,39.2096233333333],[-76.8321633333333,39.2095333333333], 
[-76.8320825997553,39.20948763515],[-76.8319866666667,39.2094333333333], 
[-76.8319816666667,39.2092766666667],[-76.83207,39.2091466666667],[-76.832225,39.20905], 
[-76.8323483333333,39.2091416666667],[-76.8322416666667,39.2093283333333], 
[-76.8321066666667,39.209475],[-76.8320825997553,39.20948763515], 
[-76.8319733333333,39.209545],[-76.831862668414,39.20954057341], 
[-76.8318483333334,39.20954],[-76.8318415539569,39.2095171966764], 
[-76.8318116666667,39.2094166666667],[-76.8318683333333,39.2093033333333], 
[-76.8319233333333,39.209195],[-76.8318483333334,39.2091033333333], 
[-76.8317466666667,39.2090916666667],[-76.8317216666667,39.209135], 
[-76.8317866666667,39.2093583333333],[-76.83182,39.2094933333333], 
[-76.8318415539569,39.2095171966764],[-76.831862668414,39.20954057341], 
[-76.8319133333333,39.2095966666667],[-76.8318683333333,39.2097], 
[-76.8318416666667,39.2097383333333],[-76.8318116666667,39.2098966666667], 
[-76.8319366666667,39.2099516666667],[-76.832085,39.21],[-76.83213,39.21008], 
[-76.8322416666667,39.2101083333333],[-76.832365,39.2100483333333], 
[-76.8324283333333,39.20996],[-76.832475,39.209885], 
[-76.83233,39.209355],[-76.8323516666667,39.209475], 
[-76.8323933333333,39.2096216666667],[-76.8324924676826,39.2096919391536], 
[-76.832525,39.209715],[-76.8326783333333,39.2096816666667], 
[-76.8327537674778,39.2096258661087],[-76.8328,39.2095916666667], 
[-76.8328766666667,39.2095216666667],[-76.8329,39.20949], 
[-76.8328744528093,39.2094841310634],[-76.8327766666667,39.2094616666667], 
[-76.8327466666667,39.2095066666667],[-76.832685,39.209635], 
[-76.83268,39.2096466666667]]   [[[-76.832895,39.20946], 
[-76.8328744528093,39.2094841310634],[-76.8327537674778,39.2096258661087], 
[-76.8327516666667,39.2096283333333],[-76.8326516666667,39.20973], 
[-76.8326416666667,39.2098316666667],[-76.8327033333333,39.2099316666667], 
[-76.83284,39.2099916666667],[-76.8329033333333,39.210025],[-76.8331,39.2101616666667], 
[-76.8332383333333,39.2102366666667],[-76.8333933333333,39.2103233333333], 
[-76.8335416666667,39.2103883333333],[-76.8336783333333,39.21044], 
[-76.8338,39.2104816666667],[-76.83389,39.2105533333333], 
[-76.83389633091,39.2105767090203],[-76.8339113352774,39.2106321097435], 
[-76.8339116666667,39.2106333333333],[-76.8338887881129,39.2106764906686], 
[-76.8338383333333,39.2107716666667],[-76.8337783333333,39.2108866666667], 
[-76.8337710512136,39.2110192012812],[-76.83377,39.2110383333333], 
[-76.8338232468397,39.2111109427531],[-76.83388,39.2111883333333], 
[-76.8340466666667,39.2111883333333],[-76.834145,39.211135], 
[-76.8341866666667,39.2110433333333],[-76.8342116666667,39.2110016666667], 
[-76.83428,39.2108766666667],[-76.8343283333333,39.210795],[-76.83439,39.2107266666667], 
[-76.8344492363899,39.2106641394387],[-76.83451,39.2106],[-76.834715,39.21045], 
[-76.8349033333333,39.2103033333333],[-76.83497,39.21014],[-76.8349733333333,39.21006], 
[-76.834985,39.21022],[-76.834865,39.2104133333333],[-76.83476,39.21059], 
[-76.8347916666667,39.21075],[-76.8350466666667,39.2108316666667], 
[-76.8352283333333,39.2107116666667],[-76.83532,39.2105266666667], 
[-76.8354483333333,39.2103633333333],[-76.83555,39.21017], 
[-76.8356666666667,39.2100466666667],[-76.8358216666667,39.21004], 
[-76.8358733333333,39.2101316666667],[-76.8358316666667,39.2102883333333], 
[-76.8359,39.210425],[-76.8358689842204,39.2104852071477],[-76.8358433333333,39.210535], 
[-76.8356983333333,39.210565],[-76.8357383333333,39.210475], 
[-76.8358689842204,39.2104852071477],[-76.8359516666667,39.2104916666667], 
[-76.8360516666667,39.210455],[-76.8361533333333,39.2102916666667], 
[-76.836285,39.210175],[-76.8364766666667,39.21023],[-76.8366683333333,39.21028], 
[-76.8368166666667,39.210305],[-76.836955,39.2103233333333], 
[-76.83699,39.2103183333333],[-76.8373016666667,39.2103166666667], 
[-76.8374566666667,39.2103016666667],[-76.8376066666667,39.21029], 
[-76.8377616666667,39.2103016666667],[-76.83795,39.210335], 
[-76.8381333333333,39.2104033333333],[-76.83831,39.2105133333333], 
[-76.8384333333333,39.2106416666667],[-76.8385183333333,39.210785], 
[-76.8385616666667,39.210935],[-76.838585,39.2110366666667], 
[-76.8386083333334,39.2111266666667],[-76.83865,39.211245], 
[-76.8387166666667,39.211505],[-76.838855,39.2116916666667], 
[-76.839035,39.2118216666667],[-76.8392,39.2119766666667],[-76.8393516666667,39.212125], 
[-76.83948,39.21218],[-76.8395733333333,39.2121633333333], 
[-76.8398377180994,39.212155736099],[-76.839863333316,39.2121550000005], 
[-76.8398633333333,39.212155],[-76.839866248213,39.2121550000002], 
[-76.8398683333333,39.212155],[-76.839885,39.212155], 
[-76.839863333316,39.2121550000005],[-76.83984,39.212155], 
[-76.8398377180994,39.212155736099],[-76.839685,39.212205], 
[-76.8395033333333,39.212245],[-76.83924,39.2121616666667], 
[-76.8390316666667,39.2119483333333],[-76.8388216666667,39.2117766666667], 
[-76.8387066666667,39.21161],[-76.838545,39.21148],[-76.8383866666667,39.211435], 
[-76.8381966666667,39.2114216666667],[-76.8380266666667,39.21142], 
[-76.8378533333333,39.2114133333333],[-76.8376933333333,39.2114116666667], 
[-76.837545,39.2113983333333],[-76.837365,39.2114166666667], 
[-76.837145,39.2113883333333],[-76.83696,39.2113683333333],[-76.8368116666667,39.21135], 
[-76.8366616666667,39.211345],[-76.8365166666667,39.21134], 
[-76.836395,39.2113383333333],[-76.83635,39.21134],[-76.8361416666667,39.21133], 
[-76.8359466666667,39.2112916666667],[-76.8358183333333,39.2112233333333], 
[-76.8357733333333,39.2111683333333],[-76.8357366666667,39.211055], 
[-76.8356816666667,39.2109716666667],[-76.83552,39.211005], 
[-76.8353483333333,39.2109983333333],[-76.8351966666667,39.2109416666667], 
[-76.835055,39.210885],[-76.8349033333333,39.21081],[-76.83475,39.2107766666667], 
[-76.834625,39.2107333333333],[-76.83449,39.2106866666667], 
[-76.8344492363899,39.2106641394387],[-76.8343633333333,39.2106166666667], 
[-76.834205,39.21054],[-76.8340283333333,39.2105483333333], 
[-76.833938122743,39.2106129286176],[-76.8339113352774,39.2106321097435], 
[-76.8338933333333,39.210645],[-76.8338216666667,39.2107666666667], 
[-76.83377,39.2108516666667],[-76.8337333333333,39.2109116666667], 
[-76.8337122666612,39.2109696000596],[-76.8336933333333,39.2110216666667], 
[-76.8337276727651,39.2110803760451],[-76.833745,39.21111], 
[-76.8338232468397,39.2111109427531],[-76.8338833333333,39.2111116666667], 
[-76.83392,39.211055],[-76.8339716666667,39.2109833333333], 
[-76.8340783333333,39.2108283333333],[-76.8340766666667,39.210725], 
[-76.8339833333333,39.2106566666667],[-76.8339611067922,39.2106613270793], 
[-76.8338887881129,39.2106764906686],[-76.83388,39.2106783333333], 
[-76.8338083333333,39.2108016666667],[-76.83373,39.2109366666667], 
[-76.8337122666612,39.2109696000596],[-76.83366,39.2110666666667], 
[-76.8335933333333,39.21119],[-76.8335266666667,39.211375],[-76.83353,39.2116183333333], 
[-76.833635,39.2118683333333],[-76.8338283333333,39.212085], 
[-76.8340583333333,39.2123116666667],[-76.8342483333333,39.21253],[-76.834345,39.21274], 
[-76.8344233333333,39.212935],[-76.8343933333333,39.21316], 
[-76.8345383333333,39.2133166666667],[-76.8347266666667,39.213195], 
[-76.8345933333333,39.2129983333333],[-76.834455,39.2127816666667], 
[-76.8343833333333,39.212615],[-76.834365,39.2125766666667], 
[-76.83429,39.2124883333333],[-76.83412,39.21229],[-76.8339066666667,39.2120766666667], 
[-76.8337066666667,39.21187],[-76.8336,39.2116516666667], 
[-76.8335816666667,39.2114666666667],[-76.8336083333333,39.211325], 
[-76.8336516666667,39.2112016666667],[-76.8337066666667,39.21111], 
[-76.8337276727651,39.2110803760451],[-76.8337710512136,39.2110192012812], 
[-76.8337716666667,39.2110183333333],[-76.8338516666667,39.2109], 
[-76.83392,39.2108133333333],[-76.83396,39.2107166666667], 
[-76.8339611067922,39.2106613270793],[-76.8339616666667,39.2106333333333], 
[-76.833938122743,39.2106129286176],[-76.83389633091,39.2105767090203], 
[-76.8338866666667,39.2105683333333],[-76.833715,39.2105016666667], 
[-76.833595,39.2104533333333],[-76.83358,39.21045],[-76.833405,39.2103716666667], 
[-76.83337,39.210365],[-76.8332116666667,39.2103166666667],[-76.8330966666667,39.21027], 
[-76.83299,39.2102233333333],[-76.83286,39.2101766666667], 
[-76.8327283333333,39.2101333333333],[-76.8325683333333,39.2100616666667], 
[-76.832535,39.2100016666667],[-76.8325183333333,39.2098966666667], 
[-76.8325066666667,39.2097333333333],[-76.8324919958592,39.209720248584], 
[-76.8323833333333,39.2096233333333],[-76.8321633333333,39.2095333333333], 
[-76.8320825997553,39.20948763515],[-76.8319866666667,39.2094333333333], 
[-76.8319816666667,39.2092766666667],[-76.83207,39.2091466666667],[-76.832225,39.20905], 
[-76.8323483333333,39.2091416666667],[-76.8322416666667,39.2093283333333], 
[-76.8321066666667,39.209475],[-76.8320825997553,39.20948763515], 
[-76.8319733333333,39.209545],[-76.831862668414,39.20954057341], 
[-76.8318483333334,39.20954],[-76.8318415539569,39.2095171966764], 
[-76.8318116666667,39.2094166666667],[-76.8318683333333,39.2093033333333], 
[-76.8319233333333,39.209195],[-76.8318483333334,39.2091033333333], 
[-76.8317466666667,39.2090916666667],[-76.8317216666667,39.209135], 
[-76.8317866666667,39.2093583333333],[-76.83182,39.2094933333333], 
[-76.8318415539569,39.2095171966764],[-76.831862668414,39.20954057341], 
[-76.8319133333333,39.2095966666667],[-76.8318683333333,39.2097], 
[-76.8318416666667,39.2097383333333],[-76.8318116666667,39.2098966666667], 
[-76.8319366666667,39.2099516666667],[-76.832085,39.21],[-76.83213,39.21008], 
[-76.8322416666667,39.2101083333333],[-76.832365,39.2100483333333], 
[-76.8324283333333,39.20996],[-76.832475,39.209885],[-76.83249,39.20984], 
[-76.8324919958592,39.209720248584],[-76.8324924676826,39.2096919391536], 
[-76.8324933333333,39.20964],[-76.8325983333333,39.2094983333333], 
[-76.8326833333333,39.2093466666667],[-76.83268,39.2091916666667], 
[-76.8324833333333,39.2091266666667],[-76.8323283333333,39.2092133333333], 
[-76.83233,39.209355],[-76.8323516666667,39.209475], 
[-76.8323933333333,39.2096216666667],[-76.8324924676826,39.2096919391536], 
[-76.832525,39.209715],[-76.8326783333333,39.2096816666667], 
[-76.8327537674778,39.2096258661087],[-76.8328,39.2095916666667], 
[-76.8328766666667,39.2095216666667],[-76.8329,39.20949], 
[-76.8328744528093,39.2094841310634],[-76.8327766666667,39.2094616666667], 
[-76.8327466666667,39.2095066666667],[-76.832685,39.209635], 
[-76.83268,39.2096466666667]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

ok found the answer, will put it here in case some one else has the same issue.
the trick is to do nested replace instead separate ones. just change this line

```
select * from(
(select replace(substring(geo,1),"[[[", "[[") as ngeo union 
DISTINCT  
(select replace 
(substring(geo,1),"]]]", "]]")) union DISTINCT select replace 
(substring(geo,1),"]],[[" ,"], ["))
```

with

```
select replace(replace(replace(substring(geo,1),"[[[", "[["),"]]]", 
"]]"),"]],[[" ,"],[" ) as ngeo
```